# How to pass value from user form to VBA sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple user form that has only one text box and one button. As user click on the button a message box should display what was typed in

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call test
End Sub

Sub test()
MsgBox TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

I have two problems :

1) userform is not displayed automatically when i open excel .

2) message box does not show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a few little things.

You need to make the userform visible with "userform1.show" so add this to your regular module:

```
Sub auto_open()
  UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

This will open the form when the file is opened. (You can run this sub with F5 in the code view window, too.)

And change your existing code in your regular code module to reference the textbox ON the form like this:

```
Sub test()
 MsgBox UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Your "CommandButton1_Click()" code in the form looks fine.

Comment: Thank you . What is `regular module` where is it ? is it module 1 ?

Comment: Michelangelo, By Regular Module I mean the one you have listed as "Module1". There are two kinds of Modules: "Code Modules" (Regular), and "Class Modules." Your "Module1" is just a regular old Module. :)

Comment: But in this case it will not automatically open . i will have to run the `auto_open ` macto to see it

Comment: @Michelangelo in the VBE double click `ThisWorkbook` object module and add 3 lines `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` new line `UserForm1.Show` and last line `End Sub`